# TFS2015 build: "One or more of the steps defined in the build does not have an associated task definition"

Tags: tfs, build, tfsbuild, tfs-2015, build-definition

For one of our build definitions (Scheduled, from monday to friday, at 2:00 AM) we receive the following error message every night:

> One or more of the steps defined in the build does not have an
>   associated task definition

Unfortunately no log is written. Manually queuing a new build works most of the time. The error occurs only for builds scheduled during the night.

I found a link:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/1170
but that link was not very helpful. They mailed to eachother and MS says they solved some caching issues. Not something we could do by our own.

So has someone the same issue and found a solution?

[image: Screenshot of failed build]

Additional inforamation:
We are using:

- Visual Studio 2015 Update 3
- Visual Studio TFS 2015
- we are using 3 build servers, but before it starts on any of the build servers, it is already crashed.
- There is no log wich can be downloaded: see picture ("Download all logs as zip" can't be clicked)
- Only message we receive is: "One or more of the steps defined in the build does not have an associated task definition."
- Source Version of failed builds is always "T". Source Version of successful builds is a number (int) -> most recent build has highest number.

**Update 20160815:**
We are using TFS 2015 **update 2.** Our architect has planned a meeting, to check if we can update to **update 3**, maybe the caching fixes from MS will do the thrick.

Answer (score 1):

We have TFS 2015u3 with the same issues. We use scheduled builds and all builds (on 2 build agents) are crashing. As suggested in the GitHub thread I disabled SSH in the TFS Console. It works now again.

Answer (score 0):

The source version "T" means the build agent are running `tf get /version:T` command which will **get the latest version** of your source code during build process. Please refer to [tf get command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/get-command) for details:

> Specifies the maximum version, or the minimum and the maximum
>   versions, to display in the history data. The default is **/version:T**
>   (the latest version).

According to your screen shot, the phenomenon looks like **the build is not picked up by any agent.** Another possibility is the build process hangs when obtaining the latest version.

You can set up a daily scheduled  build to observe if there is such a phenomenon, and you can also go to the "_diag" folder in build agent folder and event view  to check if there are any related the logs.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this issue was a bug in SSH Service. 
The fix was published by MS here:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dstfs/2017/01/06/git-clone-ssh-ci-build-issue-in-tfs-2015-3/